# Speed up Linked Server Import

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, bcp

I have several processes that run nightly that imports data from a AS400 into SQL Server using Linked Server.  Here is a sample:

```
truncate table TABLENAME

    insert into TABLENAME
    (
        BT_TID,
        BT_SEQ ,
        BT_DES ,
        BT_HRS ,
        BT_MOD ,
        BT_MSN ,
        BT_STK
    )
    select 
        BT_TID,
        BT_SEQ ,
        BT_DES ,
        BT_HRS ,
        BT_MOD ,
        BT_MSN ,
        BT_STK
    FROM OPENQUERY([ODBCSOURCE], 'select 
        BT_TID,
        BT_SEQ ,
        BT_DES ,
        BT_HRS ,
        BT_MOD ,
        BT_MSN ,
        BT_STK
     from XXXX.XXXX.TABLENAME')
```

Some of these processes take HOURS to run.

Is there a better way of doing this?  I looked into BCP, but didn't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

As heard from Microsoft, Linked Server is slow per nature (due to processing and network limitation).
If SSIS is installed on your SQL server it should be a better option.

Comment: It depends on what is causing the delay in processing.  If the problem is the network - then it probably won't improve performance to switch to anything else.  If the problem occurs during the commit to SQL Server - then moving to SSIS and setting a batch/commit size might improve the performance.